# Intuition in Riemann integral.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How does the Riemann integral "segment"?

I vaguely understand that we are not simply adding values but multiplying them before addition.

E.g we are not adding simply lenght because we would never get an area.

We are multiplying that lenght with an infinitessimal, infinetely close to 0, width.

I always thought that a continuous "sum" would be always greater than the respective countably(discrete) infinite sum.

How can the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ be greater than $\displaystyle
\int_0^\infty x^n \, dn$ when $x \in (0,1)$

I am considering only a positive real initial term and I am ignoring them(equating them with 1) because the initial term only multiplies each term as such only multiplies the entire series, integral.

Constants can be pulled out of Integrals and Sums like the distributive property allows us in finite sums.

In this case x would get infinitelly close to 1. At least that was what I expected.

Problem is it does not shoot up to 1.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+a%5Ex+dx+from+0+to+inf+%3E+(1+-+a)+%5E+-1,+0+%3E+a+%3E+1

Actually neither the opposite holds https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+a%5Ex+dx+from+0+to+inf+%3C+(1+-+a)+%5E+-1,+0+%3E+a+%3E+1

Does the intuition change with Lebesgue integrals or others' like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Other_integrals

Comment: a function with a riemann integral has a lebesgue integral and the values are the same (see e.g. http://math.ucdenver.edu/~jmandel/classes/6131s13/hw10-solution.pdf)

Comment: as to why the series is greater than the integral, try drawing a picture using boxes. for the series, you are adding up boxes where the height is x^n and the width is 1. in the integral, you should notice that the function continues to decrease inside the boxes (if you overlay the two pictures), so it couldn't possibly be more than the series

Comment: @graeme Thank you earnestly for trying to help me. Nonetheless you did not provide any new or helpful information. Please do not be discouraged from continuing to intently pursuing to help me. I am not in any way intending to insult you, trying to act "smart",run you down, carp or cavil at your comment or pour scorn on you or your comment. I genuinely did not understand at all what you meant with:  "in the integral, you should notice that the function continues to decrease inside the boxes (if you overlay the two pictures)".

Comment: @graeme Which function continues to decrease? Every number or constant is concomitantly a function. A constant function. Do you mean the integral $\displaystyle
\int_0^\infty x^n \, dn$ if you say continues I am imagining a process, an operation like differences(recurence relations) or derivatives. Saying it decreases I am imagining a negative difference or derivative. A derivative of that function with respect to which variable? Upper limit, Lower limit? And I did not understand the part where the function diminishes inside the boxes. And certainly nothing about overlaying the pictures.

Comment: this is the picture i suggested you to draw: http://i.imgur.com/SYp4xrD.png. The area under the red curve will be your integral. The area under the green/blue boxes will be your sum. It's pretty clear from the illustration that the integral will be less than the sum. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @graeme So you are adding a countably infinite sum of smaller definite integrals with a width of 1 $\displaystyle \int_0^1 1 \, dn + \displaystyle \int_1^2 0.5 \, dn + \displaystyle \int_2^3 0.25 \, dn ...$.  I got this. I asked intuitively why does the definition of integrals make the integral not equal to a Sum of uncountably infinite smaller definite integrals with a width of 1. The sum of non negative infinite positive numbers should be infinite. Equivalent to the ratio of the geometric series being 1.

Comment: @graeme We are adding uncountably many positive numbers with 0 difference. Similar to the ratio, the step getting infinitessimally small.